# MySQL: Adding more tables via "Inner Join" results in empty ResultSet

Tags: mysql, join

first of all: sorry that the keywords within the query are german. I will provide an explanation of every keyword so you can easily understand the issue.

My Database consists of 4 tables:

**mitarbeiter**(MA_ID, name…) 
contains employee data. relevant are the ID and a name (first- and lastname separated)

**stunden_auftrag**(MA_ID, gesamt…)
contains the workhours an employee has to work for a project. identified by the employee-id. For this query only the total amount (gesamt) is important

**stunden_geleistet**(MA_ID, gesamt…)
same as before with the already worked hours.

**auftrag**(MA_ID, von, bis…) 
contains the dates how long an order runs. (von means startdate, bis means enddate)

The purpose of the following query is to show me all employees whos order terminates within the next 31 days.

The query i came up with is this:

```
`SELECT  mitarbeiter.MA_ID, 
     mitarbeiter.nachname, 
     mitarbeiter.vorname,
     auftrag.von, 
     auftrag.bis, 
     DATEDIFF(auftrag.bis, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS Resttage
FROM mitarbeiter
INNER JOIN auftrag ON mitarbeiter.MA_ID = auftrag.MA_ID
HAVING Resttage >= '0' AND Resttage <= '31';`
```

This query gives me the desired Resultset. Now i want to add another requirement to the query. It should not only display employees whos order is going to terminate, but also employees who only have less than 10% of their ordered workhours left. (sth. like "    `hoursbooked - hoursworked <= hoursbooked*0.1`    ")

For this purpose I have to add joins for both tables which contain the workhours:

```
`SELECT mitarbeiter.MA_ID,
mitarbeiter.nachname,
mitarbeiter.vorname,
auftrag.von, 
auftrag.bis, 
DATEDIFF(auftrag.bis, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS Resttage,
FROM mitarbeiter
INNER JOIN auftrag ON mitarbeiter.MA_ID = auftrag.MA_ID
INNER JOIN stunden_geleistet ON auftrag.MA_ID = stunden_geleistet.MA_ID
INNER JOIN stunden_auftrag ON stunden_geleistet.MA_ID =   stunden_auftrag.MA_ID
HAVING Resttage >= '-31' AND Resttage <= '31';`
```

I know that this query doesnt filter for this requirement yet because I already get an empty resultset with this query. Only adding the Joins makes the Resultset empty although there definitely is atleast one dummy-employee which does meet all requirements to be displayed.

Sample Data:

Table "mitarbeiter"

`MA_ID    nachname    vorname
 1        Simpson     Homer`

Table "auftrag"

`MA_ID     von        bis
 1       2014-01-01   2015-01-31`

Table "stunden_gebucht"

`MA_ID     gesamt
 1         1200`

Table "stunden_geleistet"

`MA_ID     gesamt
 1         1100`

By my understanding this employee should be displayed due to meeting the conditions of the query. But the ResultSet is empty. I don't get any Syntax errors and I think that my Join structure is correct aswell. Do you have an idea what the mistake is?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,
joermunG

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this query:

```
SELECT mitarbeiter.MA_ID,
mitarbeiter.nachname,
mitarbeiter.vorname,
auftrag.von, 
auftrag.bis, 
DATEDIFF(auftrag.bis, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS Resttage,
FROM mitarbeiter
INNER JOIN auftrag ON mitarbeiter.MA_ID = auftrag.MA_ID
INNER JOIN stunden_geleistet ON auftrag.MA_ID = stunden_geleistet.MA_ID
INNER JOIN stunden_auftrag ON stunden_geleistet.MA_ID =   stunden_auftrag.MA_ID 
where DATEDIFF(auftrag.bis, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) between -31 and 31
```

Comment: @joermunG if you replace the where statement with `mitarbeiter.MA_ID=1` do get the expected result?

Comment: I found the mistake. It is really embarassing but a had a typo in the "bis" date so the range wasnt between -31 and 31 days. Sorry i had to bother you. Your query works perfectly. Thanks for you help anyway because i found the typo by executing your last tip :)